# Why there is difference in test and data interaction speed when use API vs jmeter recording

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jmeter

I have a login function in website. I have tried 2 things to create load testing plan :

1. Record login scenario using jmeter and complete load test
2. Use login API, configure in Jmeter and complete load test

I realize that 2nd option from above is faster than 1st when running load test? Can anyone help me to understand why?

Comment: can you show the 2 plans ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well-behaved test should simulate end-user behaviour as close as possible, so basically you have at least 2 requests:

   - Open login page
   - Perform login

   In addition when mimicking real browser you have to deal with a lot more data, i.e. complete HTML response, JavaScript, CSS, images, etc.
2. In case of API you have only one request consisting of username and password and one small response indicating whether login attempt successful or not.

I believe load test should be as close to reality as possible so I would recommend 1st option. Make sure that you add the next test elements to your Test Plan:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

  and follow recommendations from [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks for satisfied answer. It was looking for this. thanks again.